# What is the kafka.consumergroup.threads property?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've encountered a Kafka instance that has the property `kafka.consumergroup.threads=10`

Does this mean each Kafka consumer group will be shared among 10 Kafka threads ?

I'm unable to find any documentation that describes this property and how it should be set. I've tried searching https://docs.confluent.io/home/overview.html but it does not yield any results:

Comment: are you using spring-kafka ?

Comment: That wouldn't be in the Confluent or Apache site because it's not a the name of any consumer config. Check the documentation for the client library you are using